# Render of app component renders the hello component or what does it exactly do ?Is it jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

```
<App render={
  <Hello render={
    (bar) => <div>hi</div>
  }/>
}></App>
```

I have studied react but never seen this type of code.

Comment: It's a technique to render components using function props (see [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From React Docs:[Render Prop in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

> The term “render prop” refers to a technique for sharing code between
> React components using a prop whose value is a function.

Think of it simply as passing a `prop` to `App` but this time the `prop value` is a Component instead of normal `data type` (such as Array, String, Object etc etc).

If you have used `react-router-dom` library it uses the same concept.